# Converting mysql exported json object to a properly formatted javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

Have got a json file exported from mysql. One particular line is not a well represented json object, i'm trying to convert this to a proper array of object.

```
var data = "{"54":

             {"ID":"54",    
             "QTY":"1",     
             "NAME":"Large",    
             "TOTAL":1.86   
             }, 

            "TOTAL":10.54,          
           "313": 
           {"ID":"313",         
            "QTY":2,        
            "NAME":"Quater Pounder",        
            "TOTAL":8.68        
           } 
        }"  

//and wants to make it:  

var data =    [
   {"ID" : "54",
   "QTY" : "1",   
   "NAME": "Quarter Pounder",  
   "TOTAL": 8.68  
  },    

  {"ID":"313",
   "QTY":2,
   "NAME": "Quater Pounder",
   "TOTAL":8.68
   }
 ]
```

Comment: I'm not clear on your first data structure ... where does the extra total come from (or go) ?

Comment: Can you share how you do the mysql->json query?

This article has some pointers on how to do it and get the structure you request: http://www.thomasfrank.se/mysql_to_json.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using angular.forEach(response, function(item){}), I then created a childArray, which I pushed the result of the above into.

Please see code:

```
angular.forEach( $scope.response, function (item) {
          item.childrenList = [];
          angular.forEach( JSON.parse( item.details ), function (value, id) {
            item.childrenList.push( value );
          })
        });
```